# Call constructor after declaration

Tags: c++

This may be a very basic question. How can I call a constructor after variable declaration? For example, this is a working code:

```
// in header
class Bar
{
    SomeClass *foo;
public:
    Bar();
}

// in .cpp
Bar::Bar()
{
    foo = new SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
}
```

But how can I change this so `foo` is not a pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the comment "in class" mean? Please add a concrete example of your problem. For now I've voted to close as **lacking example**.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I've edited the question.

Comment: OK, I retracted the close vote.

Comment: **−1** There are additional vaguely specified requirements, something about computed arguments, as [noted by the OP in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425573/call-constructor-after-declaration/38425801#comment64258192_38425801), but which he apparently refuses to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `foo` is defined inside class then use constructor initializer list as follows:

```
class X {
   X() : foo(1,2,3) {}
   SomeClass foo;
};
```

If you need to calculated arguments to `foo`-s constructor then it becomes more difficult. You could add functions which would calculate your values ie.:

```
class X {
   X() : foo(initX(),initY(),initZ()) {}
   SomeClass foo;

   static int initX() { return 1;}
   static int initY() { return 2;}
   static int initZ() { return 3;}
};
```

but this is not always possible - i.e. it depends on how you calculate your values. (static is intentional as you should better not use not fully constructed class members).

You could also pass those values as constructor parameters.

Comment: Really? I mean, this must be a common problem - you have a class with some variable (class) and you want to call it's constructor with some arguments (not the default ctor). So the only solution is to use a pointer?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký see my edit2, I  think this should be the solution

Comment: Re your first edit, I deleted that comment originally but then realised that indeed it would be allowed however `foo` would be constructed twice as you say.

Comment: This solution is good but not perfect, because I need to somehow compute the constructor's arguments (it's not just static 1, 2, 3...).

Comment: "You cannot" is incorrect, but what's right for the OP's problem is difficult to say until that problem's been clarified.

Answer (score 3):

If you're declaring this outside a class it will be a global variable. To have it constructed in a .cpp file you should probably declare it extern in the header and then use the constructor you want when you declare it in the cpp

SomeModule.h:

```
extern SomeClass foo;
```

SomeModule.cpp:

```
SomeClass foo(1, 2, 3);
```

If it's a member variable of a class then you can use the constructor you want by explicitly initialising the variable in the member initialisation list of the constructor

OtherClass.h:

```
class OtherClass
{
    SomeClass foo;
    public:
      OtherClass();
}
```

OtherClass.cpp:

```
OtherClass::OtherClass() : foo(1, 2, 3) {};
```

If wanting to initialize in the middle of the code like with the pointer case then you can just let it initialize with the default constructor and copy over the value with the one you want at the same place as you would the pointer like so

```
foo = SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
class Bar
{
    SomeClass *foo;
public:
    Bar();
};

Bar::Bar()
{
    foo = new SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
}
```

… with

```
class Bar
{
private:
    SomeClass foo;

public:
    Bar();
};

Bar::Bar()
    : foo{ 1, 2, 3 }
{}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem with calculated arguments.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký: It does not solve the problem of bad sounds from the microwave oven, that's true. But that problem is not mentioned anywhere so far. What is the "problem with calculated arguments"? If it turns out to be non-trivial, please post a new question about it. Don't substantially change the existing question, because that will invalidate existing answers.